# generate a report in R where the value in each Column is to be derived from different tables in sybase databasea

Tags: r, data

I work in a stress testing team. my boss has asked me to generate an interactive report every day using different tables in a Sybase database. I know the table structure and sql queries, but can't get my head around implementing in Rstudio using shiny or markdown.

Please advise.
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good overview of recommended ways:

http://r4ds.had.co.nz/r-markdown-formats.html#r-markdown-formats

I suggest using the package `flexdashboard` (heading "Dashboards"). Interactivity can be provided by `htmlwidgets` you can find an overview here:

http://www.htmlwidgets.org/

As an example, install:

```
install.packages('flexdashboards') # the dashboard
install.packages('plotly') # for interactive graphs
install.packages('DT') # for interactive tables
install.packages('tidyverse') # for data transformation etc
```

now create a dashboard as explained on

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/

and fill it with your graph or tables. Here I use the `starwars` dataset provided in the package `dplyr`

````
---
title: "Single Column (Fill)"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
---

### Chart 1

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
datatable(starwars %>% select(-films, -vehicles, -starships))
```

### Chart 2

```{r}
g <- starwars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(height, mass, color = gender)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Mass vs. Height by gender")

library(plotly)
ggplotly(g)
```
````

output will be a `html`(interactive) file with table and graph:

[image]